# Bottom bar shape without programming

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to make something like this:

[image]

But I don't know how to make the central part.

I know that it can be made programming because others did it (with [bézier curves](https://proandroiddev.com/how-i-drew-custom-shapes-in-bottom-bar-c4539d86afd7) or Canvas), but I'd like to make it with a drawable, an image or SVG (so, without Java code). I can't use any external libraries.

The white part must be transparent, so I can't add a white circle at the bottom of the '+' button.

Currently I have a Constraint Layout, with 2 LinearLayout with background color:

[image]

Comment: you can add a white border around the + circle. but then its not transparent, but it looks like it is. unless of course if you change the color of the screen above, then the white border will not simulate transparency anymore

Comment: @duxfox-- the background have content and a gradient; the border can't be a solid color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching I found that [material.io](https://material.io/components) had the exact same design as an example:

[image: material.io example]

So I just followed the provided code tutorial.